# How to overwrite extended method?

Tags: ruby

Sample code:

```
module B
  def f2
    puts "B::f2"
  end
end

class C
  def initialize
    extend B
  end

  def f2
    puts "C::f2"
  end
end

c = C.new
c.f2
```

Above sample code is an abstraction of my problem. `Class C` extends `module B` on fly (`B` is actually extended to instance of `C`). Method `f2` from `B` doesn't meet my needs, so I want to overwrite `f2`. How to implement that?

Comment: well, you _are_ overwriting `C#f2` with one from `B`. Any reason why you do this dynamic extension instead of the usual include?

Comment: Because in my real code,`B` is a configurable plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually don't like extending in `initialize`. There are many reasons to implement "plugin" in different way.
But if you want to "shoot in the foot" this way, ok, just do one more extend:

```
module B
  def f2
    puts 'B::f2'
  end
end

class C
  attr_reader :parent_state

  def initialize
    extend B
    extend BOverrides

    @parent_state = 'Parent State'
  end

  module BOverrides
    def f2
      puts 'C::f2'
      puts 'Yes, I have access to %s' % parent_state
    end
  end
end

c = C.new
c.f2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my real code, I don't extend in initialize, I have a load_plugin method that is also not called in initialize.

Comment: I meant `extend` on the fly is not best idea. You can implement `Strategy` design pattern in more standard way. For example you can implement your plugins as classes with same interface and put its class name or instance to `C` `initialize`. Or you can create DSL which provides extending in code load time, not in runtime. Its pretty standard way to configure code for Rails and other frameworks and gems.